# Using SAML and WS-Fed auth seamlessly through same session on same ADFS3.0 box

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, web-services, saml, ws-federation

I am trying to connect two web apps (one running in Rails, the other in .Net) via ADFS3.0 for Single Sign On.  One side is coming in on a SAML2.0 token (Rails), and the other is authenticating against ADFS with WS-Fed (.Net).  Ideally, I'd like the SAML token to be passed to ADFS 3.0 and then converted to WS-Fed to allow seamless integration between Rails and .Net environments... Is this possible?

At the moment,  ADFS registers the logon has occurred from Rails, but still requires you to visit the ADFS LS (albeit this time it does not require you to type in your details).  For ease of use, this transaction has to be seamless, whereas now it "works" but requires a small amount of user input to force to conversion between WSFed and SAML.

Rough guide to how it is currently...

Rails ---> connects to --->  ADFS3.0 --- authenticates (SAML) and returns to Rails ---> redirects to .Net ---> redirects to ADFS3.0 ---> click ADFS login (no login details typed in, session still active) (WSFed) ---> Reach end point.

... and ideally....

Rails ---> connects to --->  ADFS3.0 --- authenticates (SAML) and returns to Rails ---> redirects to .Net ---> redirects to ADFS3.0 ---> ADFS3.0 recognises active SAML token, transforms to WS-Fed (if necessary) ---> Reach end point without logging in or pressing anything new.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, IN ADFS3.0, we have the following option

1. The Rails Application will hit the authorize end point
2. User does the authentication
3. Rails app gets the Authorization code
4. Rails app posts the authorization code to the ADFS token end point
5. Rails app gets back the access token
6. Then some  how gets the user profile info

In this case, there will be no requirement for you to have a .Net Application for authentication alone.

I am not sure if this would suffice your use-case. I am working now with ADFS3.0 and OAuth2 Specifications, so feel that this would be an ideal usage.